# obtaining jQuery $.load() ajax object

Tags: jquery, ajax, abort

As was demonstrated in the following link, jQuery's $.ajax call returns an ajax object that can later be used to abort the call if needed.

[Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery)

My project is using $.load(), which returns the object pattern, rather than the ajax object ( $("").load() ).

Is there a way I can obtain the ajax object from $.load?

Comment: why can't you change to use $.ajax instead so you could use the same method?

Comment: I have a project that uses $.load() everywhere, changing $.load() to $.ajax() is not a great idea. It will be great if $.load() can somehow return jqXHR object to cancel the request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with the current API. But, thanks to open source, take a look at the `load` function's source (from `jquery-1.6.2.js`):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
load: function( url, params, callback ) {
    if ( typeof url !== "string" && _load ) {
        return _load.apply( this, arguments );

    // Don't do a request if no elements are being requested
    } else if ( !this.length ) {
        return this;
    }

    var off = url.indexOf( " " );
    if ( off >= 0 ) {
        var selector = url.slice( off, url.length );
        url = url.slice( 0, off );
    }

    // Default to a GET request
    var type = "GET";

    // If the second parameter was provided
    if ( params ) {
        // If it's a function
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( params ) ) {
            // We assume that it's the callback
            callback = params;
            params = undefined;

        // Otherwise, build a param string
        } else if ( typeof params === "object" ) {
            params = jQuery.param( params, jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional );
            type = "POST";
        }
    }

    var self = this;

    // Request the remote document
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        dataType: "html",
        data: params,
        // Complete callback (responseText is used internally)
        complete: function( jqXHR, status, responseText ) {
            // Store the response as specified by the jqXHR object
            responseText = jqXHR.responseText;
            // If successful, inject the HTML into all the matched elements
            if ( jqXHR.isResolved() ) {
                // #4825: Get the actual response in case
                // a dataFilter is present in ajaxSettings
                jqXHR.done(function( r ) {
                    responseText = r;
                });
                // See if a selector was specified
                self.html( selector ?
                    // Create a dummy div to hold the results
                    jQuery("<div>")
                        // inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts
                        // to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE
                        .append(responseText.replace(rscript, ""))

                        // Locate the specified elements
                        .find(selector) :

                    // If not, just inject the full result
                    responseText );
            }

            if ( callback ) {
                self.each( callback, [ responseText, status, jqXHR ] );
            }
        }
    });

    return this;
}
}
```

A slightly dangerous but workable solution would be to copy that source and change it so that it returns what the `ajax` call returns, instead of `return this`. It's dangerous because it may rely on internal jquery behavior, which could change without notice in a future version.

I would probably extend jQuery.fn with a new function with a different name, perhaps loadAjax

If you're using a different version of jquery, take it from there.